# Using Leaflet with OpenStreetMaps to outline buildings

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm quite new to using OpenStreetMaps, Leaflet and javascript in general for that matter, but I have a small map taken from OSM, and I want to place leaflet polygons over each building.

How would I go about taking the outline of a building from OSM, and converting each outline into a polygon? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a task for Overpass API. You should be able to find some examples on the Internet.